# Question about Negative Binomial Distribution

Tags: probability

Customers come into a store. $30\%$ of them make a purchase.

a) Calculate the probability that the second purchase is made by the sixth customer.

Answer: As the last purchase is made by the sixth customer,
we have a binomial with n=5 times the probability of the last purchase.

The probability is $C(5,1) (0.3) \cdot 0.7^4 \cdot 0.3$ = 0.108045

b)Calculate the expected value of the sequence number of the customer who makes the second purchase.

I have several questions related to part b):

***1) What is a sequence number?***

2) The question is part of the probability manual written by Abraham Weishauss. Weishauss answer is to find the expected value and add 2. ***My question is why? Weishauss does not explain that.***

For the Negative Binomial Distribution, the expected value is $k\cdot(1-p)/p$.

For that reason the expected value is $2 \cdot (1-0.3)/0.3 = 14/3$

Adding 2 to that, Weishauss says that the answer is $20/3$

3) Weishauss explanation is "The negative binomial mean measures the number of customers between the second one and the one making the purchase. Therefore, we add 2 to the mean to get the sequence number of the customer making the purchase."

***I do not understand this explanation. May you expand this answer?***

I like to understand the ideas. I do not see the intuition behind this answer.

Comment: "*What is a sequence number?*"  Presumably it's a very awkward wording of asking which person it was who was the second to purchase something (*was it the second person? the third person? the fourth?...*)  "*Why do we add 2?*"  Check to see what the expected value of the negative binomial distribution you cite represents.  If it only represents the total number of people expected to have *not* purchased items prior to the second purchase, then we would also want to consider the two people who purchased things as well in our count.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks for your help! However, I do not understand your comment. In my perspective it is clear that it was the sixth who made the second purchase because in the negative binomial you need a success at the end of experiment. Am I right?

Comment: @JMoravitz Also I cannot add anything because that is all the information available.

Comment: "*It is clear that it was the sixth who made the second purchase*"... Why?  It is possible that there could have been a hundred people who all came in and shopped and didn't purchase a single thing before even a single item was sold.  There is no reason to think the sixth person must the be the second purchaser.

Comment: @JMoravitz Please accept my apologies. I did not publish something that is fundamental. I will make the correction in the question right away.

Comment: So, in the first part of the question, we ask what the probability is that the sixth person is the second to purchase something.  Now that that question is out of the way, we begin working on the second part of the question.  In this second part of the question, *we no longer are assuming the sixth person is the second to purchase anything!*  That assumption was for the first part of the question only, and has nothing to do with the second part.  If we *were* working with that assumption... then the answer would obviously be six and there would be no calculation required.

Comment: @JMoravitz Amazing comment! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: The following explanation tried to match your notation as best as possible and so the roles of $p$ and $1-p$ may be reversed from how you normally see written for geometric or negative binomial random variables.  In the end, always check to see what the role of $n,p,k$ are meant to represent in any problem and in any formula you are attempting to use.*

---

**1)** "*What is a sequence number?*"  Presumably it's a very awkward wording of asking which person it was who was the second to purchase something (*was it the second person? the third person? the fourth?...*)

Imagine that there is someone guarding the door to the shop who only allows one person into the store at a time and greets people saying "Hello and welcome!  You are the __'th person to visit today!"

---

**2)** "*Why do we add 2?*"  Check to see what the expected value of the negative binomial distribution you cite represents.  The negative binomial distribution is commonly originally worded as counting the number of successes which occur before the $k$'th failure with probability of failure as $p$ (*successes here referring to people not purchasing anything, and failure here corresponding to people making a purchase*).  The expected value here being given by $\frac{k(1-p)}{(p)}$.

Using this description of the negative binomial distribution and this expected value, what we would have calculated when we did $\frac{2(1-0.3)}{0.3}$ is in fact just the total number of people who didn't make a purchase.  We were asked to find the expected number of people *total* including those people who didn't make a purchase *as well as* those people who made a purchase.  So, since there are an average of $\frac{2(1-0.3)}{0.3}$ people who make a didn't make a purchase, in order to account for those two people who did make a purchase we add two.

We could have instead used the related formula $\frac{k}{p}$ which counts the expected number of total trials (successes *and* failures) which occur by the time of the $k$'th success where probability of failure is $p$.  This expected value is perhaps easier to derive as you can think of it as $k$ consecutive geometric random variables, each with expected value $\frac{1}{p}$.  Note: $\frac{2}{0.3}=2+\frac{2(1-0.3)}{0.3}$

Comment: I love how you explain your ideas!

Answer (score 3):

> ***1) What is a sequence number?***

The indexed count in the sequence.

> 2) The question is part of the probability manual written by Abraham Weishauss. Weishauss answer is to find the expected value and add 2. ***My question is why? Weishauss does not explain that.***
>
> For the Negative Binomial Distribution, the expected value is k*(1-p)/p.

Where $p$ is the success rate, and $k$ is the count for successes, then $k(1-p)/p$ is the expected count of *failures before* success $\#k$.  It does not include the successes.

> For that reason the expected value is 2*(1-0.3)/0.3 = 14/3
>
> Adding 2 to that, Weishauss says that the answer is 20/3

So, adding the two successes gives us the count for *trials until* the second success.

> 3) Weishauss explanation is "The negative binomial mean measures the number of customers between the second one and the one making the purchase. Therefore, we add 2 to the mean to get the sequence number of the customer making the purchase."

***I do not understand this explanation. May you expand this answer?***

---

A Geometric distribution counting the *failures before the first success* has a mean of $(1-p)/p$.

So the expected count of *failures before the first success*, the first success, *failures from then before the second success*, and the second success is $2(1-p)/p+2$  or simply $2/p$.

Comment: Thank you for your amazing answer!